# how to add icon into text flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, text, icons

i have a simple code

```
              RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    model.resetmodem();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Size (also 24 pixels, not coincidentally, since both FlutterLogo and Icon honor the ambient IconTheme). This leaves some room left over, and now the row tells the text exactly how wide to be: the exact width of the remaining space. The text, now happy to comply to a reasonable request, wraps the text ',
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                ),
```

I want to add an icon in front of the text but I don't want to overflow the text

Comment: which Icon? There is no icon in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Row and put this text and icon inside it if it overflows you got to lower font sized or icon size or make your button bigger

Answer (score 0):

You could you RichText along with InkWell like:

```
            InkWell(
             onTap: () {
                  //Your code here
                },
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text: 'Size (also 24 pixels, not coincidentally, since both FlutterLogo and Icon honor the ambient IconTheme). This leaves some room left over, and now the row tells the text exactly how wide to be: the exact width of the remaining space. The text, now happy to comply to a reasonable request, wraps the text ',
                      children: [
                        WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.done)),
                      ]),
                ),
              )
```